# Object-specific code for global C++ objects?

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, inline

Consider the following C++-pseudocode:

```
class C { 
   int a,b,c;
   inline void simple_method() { /* whatever */ }
   void complex_method();
}
C foo,bar;

int main() {
   foo.complex_method();
   bar.simple_method();
}
```

OK. Now the generated assembly code for `bar.simple_method()` will obviously contain direct references to the variables bar.a, bar.b and so on, i.e. it will **not** go through an object pointer.

The non-inlined method, however, will access everything through an object pointer. But since I am programming an embedded controller which either has limited addressing capabilities or which GCC doesn't understand too well, the resulting assembly code is really slow and bloated.

Using `always_inline` generates fast and reasonably neat code. But since there are multiple callers to complex_method(), this is not a viable solution.

The best way to solve this problem I've managed to come up with is to slap an `always_inline` onto `X::complex_method()`, create a heap of wrappers along the lines of

```
 void _foo_complex_method() { foo.complex_method(); }
```

and then remember to always use these wrappers.

This is a no-brainer if you have one class, one complex method, and two globals, like in this example. The problem is that our current design has rather more of these – and keeping the argument lists and return values of all of these wrappers straight is a major headache; besides, I discover new direct calls to the methods every week. :-/

Thus, I wonder if there's an easier idiom (possibly implemented in interestingly-complex templates and all that stuff which C++ is infamous for ;-) with which to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Why not add a semi-colon and make it real C++ code? :)

Comment: `bar.simple_method() will obviously contain direct references to the variables bar.a, bar.b and so on, i.e. it will not go through an object pointer` Why is this "obvious"? Is it even definitely true?

Comment: It's true because the compiler knows the addresses (it's a global variable) and thus can optimize the constant "this" object pointer away. And yes, GCC does that, I've checked. It'd be very stupid not to, given x86's very limited number of registers.